# Double checked locking on Dictionary "ContainsKey"

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, dictionary, double-checked-locking

My team is currently debating this issue.

The code in question is something along the lines of

```
if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    lock (_SyncObject)
    {
        if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            myDictionary.Add(key,value);
        }
    }
}
```

Some of the posts I've seen say that this may be a big NO NO (when using TryGetValue). Yet members of our team say it is ok since "ContainsKey" does not iterate on the key collection but checks if the key is contained via the hash code in O(1). Hence they claim there is no danger here.

I would like to get your honest opinions regarding this issue.

Comment: you may want to check out ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: Just a detail but you probably mean `!ContainsKey()`

Comment: Have you found efficiency problems from locking the whole dictionary?

Comment: the dictionary will be used as a static cache. so this check is do for each instance creation. so thats a lot of locking...

Comment: But have you actually found any efficiency problems? It's sometimes better not to worry about problems until they occur.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't do this. It's not safe.

You could be calling `ContainsKey` from one thread while another thread calls `Add`. That's simply not supported by `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. If `Add` needs to reallocate buckets etc, I can imagine you *could* get some very strange results, or an exception. It *may* have been written in such a way that you don't see any nasty effects, but I wouldn't like to rely on it.

It's one thing using double-checked locking for simple reads/writes to a field, although I'd still argue against it - it's another to make calls to an API which has been explicitly described as *not* being safe for multiple concurrent calls.

If you're on .NET 4, [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) is probably the way forward. Otherwise, just lock on every access.

Comment: What if this code is accessed a lot within the application? Then that might be a performance issue. Any other way to do this besides ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: @Amir: I'd rather suffer a tiny amount of performance loss than have the application blow up. Have you profiled the application to see whether this is causing an *actual* performance issue? Uncontested locks are cheap: don't start trying to roll your own lock-free code without proving that you *really* need it.

Comment: Am i correct to assume that if i go with a lock on access instead of DCL then i will need to lock every access in every method to this dictionary?

Comment: @Amir: Yes. You could potentially use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to allow concurrent readers, but I'd just try locking on *every* access first, and profile your application to see whether it's a problem.

Comment: Sadly there are side-effects. If another thread calls Add while you check for ContainsKey there's a good chance the code checking for key will enter a loop and your application will hang.

Comment: We just had this happen with the side effect of high CPU and possibly failed requests.  Here's a nice post that explains in more detail: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2009/12/21/high-cpu-in-net-app-using-a-static-generic-dictionary/

Comment: @JarJarrr "What if this code is accessed a lot within the application?" - I added a possible solution for low write volume scenarios below :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are in a multithreaded environment, you may prefer to look at using a ConcurrentDictionary. I blogged about it a couple of months ago, you might find the article useful: http://colinmackay.co.uk/blog/2011/03/24/parallelisation-in-net-4-0-the-concurrent-dictionary/

Comment: What is an ample solution to this issue if using .Net 4.0 is not an option? (using 3.5)

Comment: Good alternative and article but it doesn't actually answer whether the proposed locking is "OK".

Answer (score 6):

This code is incorrect.  The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type does not support simultaneous read and write operations.  Even though your `Add` method is called within the lock the `ContainsKey` is not.  Hence it easily allows for a violation of the simultaneous read / write rule and will lead to corruption in your instance

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look thread-safe, but it would probably be hard to make it fail.

The iteration vs hash lookup argument doesn't hold, there could be a hash-collision for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If this dictionary is rarely written and often read, then I often employ safe double locking by replacing the entire dictionary on write. This is particularly effective if you can batch writes together to make them less frequent.

For example, this is a cut down version of a method we use that tries to get a schema object associated with a type, and if it can't, then it goes ahead and creates schema objects for all the types it finds in the same assembly as the specified type to minimize the number of times the entire dictionary has to be copied:

```
    public static Schema GetSchema(Type type)
    {
        if (_schemaLookup.TryGetValue(type, out Schema schema))
            return schema;

        lock (_syncRoot) {
            if (_schemaLookup.TryGetValue(type, out schema))
                return schema;

            var newLookup = new Dictionary<Type, Schema>(_schemaLookup);

            foreach (var t in type.Assembly.GetTypes()) {
                var newSchema = new Schema(t);
                newLookup.Add(t, newSchema);
            }

            _schemaLookup = newLookup;

            return _schemaLookup[type];
        }
    }
```

So the dictionary in this case will be rebuilt, at most, as many times as there are assemblies with types that need schemas. For the rest of the application lifetime the dictionary accesses will be lock-free. The dictionary copy becomes a one-time initialization cost of the assembly. The dictionary swap is thread-safe because pointer writes are atomic so the whole reference gets switched at once.

You can apply similar principles in other situations as well.